# Encrypt Entire Rails Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, encryption

I'd like to encrypt basically the entire database for my rails application (or at least many of the tables / columns) because I'm hosting a lot of sensitive data for clients. I'm using MySQL at the moment, but I could switch if necessary. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet for encryption would be to make a encrypted partition on one of your drives, or possibly a virtual encrypted drive, then move the mysql data storage over to the encrypted partition.  Note that you would need to enter the password on system boot to mount the partition, but if you automatically entered it the security would be useless.  Basically this would protect you from physical intrusion or theft of the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: [How to secure user data in the database with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634926/how-to-secure-user-data-in-the-database-with-rails)

My suggestion would be to use the [safe (strongbox)](https://github.com/bitzesty/safe) gem.