# Not able to use openssl in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, openssl, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to use asymmetric encryption in Ruby on Rails. For this, I am trying to use openssl library. First I created keys inside a model named `Manufacturer`.

```
def create_verification_keys
  keypair = DigitalSign.generate_keypair
  self.private_key = keypair.to_s
  self.public_key = keypair.public_key.to_s
end
```

After this, inside the controller, I wrote:

```
@privatekey=Manufacturer.first.private_key 
@publickey=Manufacturer.first.public_key
$hash=Digest::MD5.hexdigest("abcd")
$encrypted_string = Base64.encode64(@privatekey.private_encrypt($hash))
```

But when I run it, it returns the following error:

```
"undefined method `private_encrypt' for #<String:0x00007f3e107c2360> Did you mean? private_methods"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs, because `@privatekey` instance variable is of type `String`, and does not have `private_encrypt` method.

It is string, because in the method `create_verification_keys` you do the following:

```
self.private_key = keypair.to_s
self.public_key = keypair.public_key.to_s
```

`to_s` here explicitly converts the object to string, and it is OK, because the database expects, stores and returns a simple string (in this case), not a complex object.

To fix that you first need to instantiate the proper type. If you use openssl gem, probably, it should be something like that:

```
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@privatekey)
rsa.private_encrypt($hash)
```

Documentation reference [here](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html).

Comment: @Maksim..Thanks for answering my question. I understand what you are trying to say and I should not use string for storing the key files because it does not help in encryption. What should I do then? I need to store the keys in DB for later use, I cannot store them in files because I would be generating a lot of key pairs.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal You can store these keys in the database and use them for encryption. It is not a secure way, but the implementation in general will work. Look at [the examples](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html#top) of building `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` object. They use `File.read` there, and it also returns a string. So all you need to make it work - just construct the `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` first, and after that invoke `private_encrypt` on it. You can even declare a method on `Manufacturer` model that will return the prepared object.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal However, I would recommend you also to research other ways of storing such sensitive data as private keys, because in the database in current implementation they will be stored as a plain text. So if some hacker gains an access to the db, they will easily read them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634926/how-to-secure-user-data-in-the-database-with-rails) [are](https://medium.com/@lstigile/youre-not-storing-sensitive-data-in-your-database-seriously-c69a1c145433) some links where you can find the info on related topics.